# Fields and Conductors

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

Is it correct to say that the field exiting the conductor is less than the field entering the conductor as the internal field of the conductor due to the induced charges is opposite in direction?

Answer (score 0):

Since the conductor will be in electrostatic equilibrium, the charges inside it will distribute such that the electric field inside it opposes and neutralizes the external electric field to with it is subjected. However, this is only local to the interior of the conductor, since, due to Gauss' law, the electric field at the surface of it has to be zero. This is because the total charge on the conductor is zero. Essentially, the external field is only counteracted while passing through the conductor, and is of expected magnitude and direction everywhere else.